# How to insert infinite records in mysql from php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert multiple records in mysql from php. How to pass list to mysql table.Please suggest your solution.

```
$course[0] = 1;
$course[1] = 'test';
$course[2] = 'test1'
$sql = "INSERT INTO temp_course(uniqueId,fullName,shortName) VALUES($course[0],'$course[1]','$course[2]')";
```

i tried like above. but values not inserted.

Comment: `mysqli` or `pdo`?

Comment: please describe your list ...  (of infinite??? record)

Comment: mysqli. Error : syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: you forgot `;` after `$course[2] = 'test1'`

Comment: okay.now the error was removed.But the values not updating in table.

Answer (score -1):

@Gopal you can try with implode() but make sure your array sequence must be same as your table column sequence given by you in query, try like below:

```
<?php
    $course[0] = 1;
    $course[1] = 'test';
    $course[2] = 'test1';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_course(uniqueId,fullName,shortName) VALUES(".implode(',', $course).")";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping the variables with curly brackets like this:

```
    $course = [];
    $course[0] = 1;
    $course[1] = 'test';
    $course[2] = 'test1';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_course(uniqueId,fullName,shortName) VALUES($course[0],'$course[1]','$course[2]')";
```